# VS 2017 NGROK reports not installed after installing

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ngrok

Walking through Twilio tutorial which recommends using NGROK with VS2017.
Find the extension easily enough and installs (have to close VS2017 and reopen) and sure enough the NGROK menu option is clearly "THERE" when I reload the project...yet when I select the menu option (Tools -> Start ngrok tunnel) I get the unfathomable message:
[image]

Ok, so maybe it is not installed "all the way" and so I select YES and shortly receive an null reference exception:

[image]

The instructions to install this is dirt simple...but I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was receiving the same error message.  There is actually an ngrok tree under Tools.. Options where you can set the path yourself.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After some digging and testing I found the right combination. In order to get the ngrok plugin to work with Visual Studio the ngrok executable has be installed in an accessible location on the local machine. The plug in is *not* a 'stand alone' utility, merely a shortcut to get the right options sent into ngrok from your VS project (most notably, the port #).

1. Download ngrok
2. Extract it to either

   - someplace already in your PATH or
   - someplace you add to your PATH
     (so that VS can find it)
3. Activate ngrok with your access code
4. Install VS Plugin
5. Have fun with ngrok.

(as for why it won't download and install ngrok as advertised, I still don't know that one...)

Comment: One of the paths normally exist is "C:\Windows" So, copy the "ngrok.exe" to the path works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @JeeShenLee that will _work_ but if you repeat that you will just clutter your c:\windows with 'stuff not window'. You might be prepared to loose it next time Windows updates runs as well.